# Latency of infinite loop when netty tries to open a server side socket?

Tags: netty

I am reading the source code of Netty, in ServerBootstrap.bind(final SocketAddress localAddress) method, I found there may be an infinite loop when an InterruptedException is thrown(check the code below), is my understanding right?

```
do {
    try {
        future = futureQueue.poll(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        interrupted = true;
    }
} while (future == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is right.. Can you please open a bug-report [1] ?

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues